# Rewriterule redirects to http by default

Tags: apache, redirect, mod-rewrite

It seems like Apache redirects to http by default even if it's a https request. We have thousands of rewrite rules like:

```
RewriteRule ^/testredirect$ /contact.html [R=301,NC,L,NE]
```

If the request is https://www.example.com/testredirect, redirect basically works like this:

```
https://www.example.com/testredirect =>  http://www.example.com/contact => https://www.example.com/contact
```

Second redirect caused by our default http to https rule on top of everything. This causes 2 redirects which affects SEO.

Is it possible to redirect with preserving the requested protocol by using the relative urls? Or should we update all of our redirect rules by setting a full url like:

```
RewriteRule ^/testredirect$ https://example.com/contact.html [R=301,NC,L,NE]
```

Related rewrite logs:

```
[Tue Dec 13 13:56:37.992575 2016] [rewrite:trace2] [pid 9268:tid 139924464367360] mod_rewrite.c(468): [client xxx.xx.xx.xx:4882] xxx.xx.xx.xx - - [www.example.com/sid#7f42ca487138][rid#7f42c40a60a0/initial] init rewrite engine with requested uri /testredirect
[Tue Dec 13 13:56:37.992628 2016] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 9268:tid 139924464367360] mod_rewrite.c(468): [client xxx.xx.xx.xx:4882] xxx.xx.xx.xx - - [www.example.com/sid#7f42ca487138][rid#7f42c40a60a0/initial] applying pattern '^/testredirect$' to uri '/testredirect'
[Tue Dec 13 13:56:37.992639 2016] [rewrite:trace2] [pid 9268:tid 139924464367360] mod_rewrite.c(468): [client xxx.xx.xx.xx:4882] xxx.xx.xx.xx - - [www.example.com/sid#7f42ca487138][rid#7f42c40a60a0/initial] rewrite '/testredirect' -> '/contact.html'
[Tue Dec 13 13:56:37.992646 2016] [rewrite:trace2] [pid 9268:tid 139924464367360] mod_rewrite.c(468): [client xxx.xx.xx.xx:4882] xxx.xx.xx.xx - - [www.example.com/sid#7f42ca487138][rid#7f42c40a60a0/initial] explicitly forcing redirect with http://www.example.com/contact.html
[Tue Dec 13 13:56:37.992654 2016] [rewrite:trace1] [pid 9268:tid 139924464367360] mod_rewrite.c(468): [client xxx.xx.xx.xx:4882] xxx.xx.xx.xx - - [www.example.com/sid#7f42ca487138][rid#7f42c40a60a0/initial] redirect to http://www.example.com/contact.html [REDIRECT/301]
[Tue Dec 13 13:56:38.161545 2016] [rewrite:trace2] [pid 9268:tid 139924489545472] mod_rewrite.c(468): [client xxx.xx.xx.xx:4882] xxx.xx.xx.xx - - [www.example.com/sid#7f42ca487138][rid#7f42c40a00a0/initial] init rewrite engine with requested uri /contact.html
[Tue Dec 13 13:56:38.161583 2016] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 9268:tid 139924489545472] mod_rewrite.c(468): [client xxx.xx.xx.xx:4882] xxx.xx.xx.xx - - [www.example.com/sid#7f42ca487138][rid#7f42c40a00a0/initial] applying pattern '^/testredirect$' to uri '/contact.html'
[Tue Dec 13 13:56:38.161592 2016] [rewrite:trace1] [pid 9268:tid 139924489545472] mod_rewrite.c(468): [client xxx.xx.xx.xx:4882] xxx.xx.xx.xx - - [www.example.com/sid#7f42ca487138][rid#7f42c40a00a0/initial] pass through /contact.html
```

Comment: Apache is not redirecting to http by default, there must be something else (in .conf files or .htaccess) doing this redirect

Comment: @DusanBajic I double checked after your comment but there's nothing else besides the specified rule. Also added the related logs to question.

Comment: Is there a Load Balancer prehaps in front of this Apache?

Comment: @DusanBajic yes there's an ELB in front of apache

Comment: and the rule saying "443 (HTTPS, IAM Certificate: xxx) forwarding to 80 (HTTP)". Do you think this is related?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like HTTPS is terminated on ELB and that traffic that reaches your Apache is always plain HTTP (that is why the first redirect sent from Apache is to `http://...`, Apache is not simply aware that initial request was made with `https://`. Once the second request comes in (`http://www.example.com/contact`) it will skip your `/testredirect` rule and hit your default `http->https` redirect.

If you just want to always redirect to `https://`, just change your rewrite rules as you suggested:

```
RewriteRule ^/testredirect$ https://example.com/contact.html [R=301,NC,L,NE]
```